# IDE to expand and collapse JavaScript code blocks

Tags: javascript, ide, expand, region, code-folding

I find it difficult to code in JavaScript when there are so many nested functions or objects within one another that it makes it difficult to modify your code without breaking it.  What IDE can be used to expand and collapse code blocks (or lexical scope levels) within JavaScript source code, similar to how regions work in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For old-fashioned IDE, try **Eclipse: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-javascript-web-developers/heliosr**

But I highly recommend using **Sublime Text: http://www.sublimetext.com/**

SublimeText doesn't collapse/expand, but it does display gutter lines to indicate how many tab indentations each block of code is. If you go to their site, look at the first demo slide, it shows the indentation of code blocks.

Comment: damn, this Sublime Text is amazing, and so simple!  I'm spending the $70.  It's well worth it!  Think about how much more a developer would save on productivity with the black background and being able to see what they're doing.

Comment: Yeah it's very awesome! Don't forget to check out the packages too http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control/installation. It'll blow your mind! Get [JSHint plugin](https://github.com/uipoet/sublime-jshint) to check your JavaScript on-save.